# Redirecting "time" command output to file in Cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin

I'm trying to redirect the result of "time" command in Cygwin to a file, and I'm not sure how to do it.
I've tried `time app.exe > /file/path/file.txt`, `(time app.exe) > /file/path/file.txt`, `time > /file/path/file.txt app.exe` , and so on.. Frankly, whatever I could think of.

All of the above either output app.exe (which is just a stupid app that prints a few characters) to file.txt, and not the time it took to run..

also tried with -o, but it `bash: -o command not found`

So, how should I do it? And is the usage of a full path a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here, one is that `time` prints to STDERR (standard error) not STDOUT (standard output) so you will need to redirect that. This is done using this notation: `2>`. The other problem is that `time` runs another command and you need to separate the two.

The solution is to use a subshell `( )` and you had it *almost* right:

```
(time app.exe ) 2> \file\path\file.txt
```

or

```
time ( app.exe ) 2> \file\path\file.txt
```

Comment: Never would have guessed that..